# Modular exponentiation of large number

Tags: python, cryptography, sage, largenumber, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently working with a large number for cryptography.

```
a = 3087646334 

p = 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301611

b = int((p-1)/2).
```

Euler's Criterion says that

> a^b (mod p) = 1 or a^b (mod p) = p-1.

SAGE gives the correct answer and python gives wrong answer. Why is that?

- Expected Output - `1 or p-1`
- SAGE Output - `1`
- Python Output - `1047939464127281862631850078334726680804120494559424004614779`

The code is in below.

Sage

```
a = 3087646334 
p = 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301611
b = int((p-1)/2)

power_mod(a,b,p)
```

[image]

Python

```
a = 3087646334
p = 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301611
b = int((p-1)/2)

pow(a,b,p)
```

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. [Post CODE, not PICTURES of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using float division, which is inaccurate. Use `b = (p-1) // 2` instead.